# How can I search for a string between certain line numbers?

Tags: line-numbers, search

This is a problem I had recently. I have a file with several hundred lines of text. How can I search for a string between two specific line numbers? For e.g. I want to search between line numbers 100 and 325.

Answer (score 7):

```
:100,235g/foo/#<CR>
```

then press `:147<CR>` to jump to the desired line.

You can also use `:ilist`:

```
:100,235il foo<CR>
```

See `:help range`, `:help :global` and `:help :ilist`.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to search between particular lines.

```
/%>{linenumber}l\%<{linenumber}{pattern}
```

Example:

```
/%>199l\%<300lgood
```

This will search from line 200 to 299 for the pattern 'good'.

```
%>199l - l is for line, >199 denotes the lines greater than 199
```

Answer (score 2):

```
100GV325G<esc>
/\v%Vpattern
```

- `100GV325G<esc>` visually select lines from 100 to 325, return to `normal` mode.
- `/\v%Vpattern` use `:h /\%V` to limit search ranges to last visual area.

If your pattern contains newline, you must add another `\%V` to restrict pattern end in visual area:

```
100GV325G<esc>
/\v%Vpattern%V
```

- `:h /\%V`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to search for a given symbol within a function/method

```
  void f(bool b)
  {
    b;
    b;
  }

  void g(bool b)
  {
    b;  
    b;  
    b;  
    b;  
  }
```

In order to search for `b` in `f()` only:

- go to `{` of `f()`
- enter visual mode with `V`
- go to end of `f()` with '%'
- go to exec line with ':' command.
- once you are in command line input `il b` to get
  `:'<,'>il b`

After `<CR>`(enter) you get

```
b.cpp
  1:   15     b;
  2:   16     b;
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Welcomr to [vi.se]! How is this substantially different from romainl’s answer?

Comment: Thanks! Firstly, I believe that people new to vim and not familiar with ```%``` and visual mode can find them useful. Secondly, there is no need to explicitly input the range of lines.

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest explaining how their usage is relevant and keys into the `ilist`